# how to play high size audio files in audio tag HTML

Tags: php, html, audio, zend-framework

```
<audio src="/audioFiles/song.mp3" controls>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This is the code i have used to play audio files. It is working fine with low sized files. Is there any way to play high sized audio files in html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have installed **sox**  and converted the high size audio file using this **shell exec**

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/sox $oldVoice -r 8000 -c1 $newVoice -q -G");
```

Now its playing!